# AR.js Virtual Location Based Gallery

Tags: javascript, three.js, ar.js

I am looking to create a virtual gallery. I want to hang pictures and place objects on surfaces (so surface aware, such as walls, tables, outside on pavement) and also be location aware (where the physical location of the gallery will be and around the town. How can I achieve this? Thought using three.js and ar.js would give something. But not sure how to proceed. Mainly surface detection and location using AR.js. Is it possible to do this with the below libraries?
(AR.js with Image Tracking + Location Based AR)

```
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js">
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/three.js/build/ar-nft.js">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very open-ended question and I suspect that it will be difficult to give your question a satisfying and detailed answer. Have you looked at the documentation for three.js and ar.js? I believe that there are tutorials online that can put you on the right track to build your web application.

Comment: With simple examples from AR.js documentation (https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/#import-the-library), I am able to place objects at locations, but the necessity to be able to do this with surface detection is the challenge. Looking for some help!